# Java - Programs recognizes hexadecimal

Tags: java, operators

So i have this code which recognizes the lexemes which are put into and show which group they belong into. For instance if input is 1, answer will show INT for integer. I want to add new operators **, &, &&, |, ||  how can i do this ?

```
package GUI;

import java.io.*;

public class Lexan {

    public static enum Lex {
        PRINT, ID, INT, PRIRAD, ROVNASA, PLUS, MINUS, KRAT, DELENO, EOF
    }

    public static Lex lex;
    public static int num;
    public static String id;

    private static String str;
    private static char znak;

    private static void setString(String s) {
        str = s;
        index = 0;
        nextChar();
    }

    private static int index;

    private static void nextChar() {
        if (index >= str.length())
            znak = (char) 0;
        else {
            znak = str.charAt(index);
            index++;
        }
    }

    public static class LexException extends Exception {
        public LexException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }

    private static void error(String err) throws LexException {
        throw new LexException(err);
    }

    public static void nextLex() throws LexException {

        while (znak == ' ' || znak == '\t')
            nextChar();

        switch (znak) {
            case '=':
                nextChar();
                if (znak == '=') {
                    nextChar();
                    lex = Lex.ROVNASA;
                    return;
                } else {
                    lex = Lex.PRIRAD;
                    return;
                }
            case '+':
                nextChar();
                lex = Lex.PLUS;
                return;
            case '-':
                nextChar();
                lex = Lex.MINUS;
                return;
            case '*':
                nextChar();
                lex = Lex.KRAT;
                return;
            case '/':
                nextChar();
                lex = Lex.DELENO;
                return;
            case (char) 0:
                lex = Lex.EOF;
                return;
            default:
                if (Character.isDigit(znak)) {
                    num = Integer.parseInt("" + znak);
                    nextChar();
                    while (Character.isDigit(znak)) {
                        num = num * 10 + Integer.parseInt("" + znak);
                        nextChar();
                    }
                    lex = Lex.INT;
                    return;
                } else if (Character.isLetter(znak)) {
                    id = "" + znak;
                    nextChar();
                    while (Character.isLetterOrDigit(znak)) {
                        id = id + znak;
                        nextChar();
                    }
                    if (id.equals("print"))
                        lex = Lex.PRINT;
                    else
                        lex = Lex.ID;
                    return;
                } else
                    error("Nezn�my znak " + znak);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = "";

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Vstup: ");
            s = reader.readLine();
            if (s.length() == 0) break;

            setString(s);

            try {
                do {
                    nextLex();
                    switch (lex) {
                        case ID:
                            System.out.println(lex + " " + id);
                            break;
                        case INT:
                            System.out.println(lex + " " + num);
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println(lex);
                    }

                } while (lex != Lex.EOF);
            } catch (LexException e) {
                System.out.println("Chyba: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you do it?  I imagine it is possible.

Comment: Well yes i guess it is part of my school project assigment but i am cornered.

Comment: you would need to add them to your Lex enum (whatever your category is) then add logic in the switch to recognize them.  That should get you pointed in the right direction